Atomic force is weaker than nuclear force? A terminology question
I'm reading Megawatts and Megatons and on page 15 came across a statement I don't recognize:

The nuclear force acting on a single proton is approximately what is
needed to support a mass of a hundred kilograms, while the atomic
force is about what is required to hold up a microgram...

I'm familiar enough with nuclear force, and I loved the way they use everyday units here (I'll be sure to quote it in the future!) but I have not come across that second term before, at least not like this. At first, I was "what's the difference between atomic and nuclear?"
They do not define it, but from the context, it seems they are referring to an analog of the nuclear force being a "leftover" from the strong force and this is the inter-atomic force forming molecules etc.  I managed to get through undergrad never using it, we always spoke of various "bonds", not some generalized "force".
So I googled it. That turned up many pages on the topic, but these were 100% related to AFM. In the past, I always parsed AFM as "an atomic-scale force microscope" as opposed to "atomic-force microscope", but perhaps that is incorrect. I then read several introductory-level texts and pages on the forces holding atoms in molecules, and not a single one uses this term to describe this.
So...
Is the term "atomic force" in this context referring to the various inter-atomic electromagnetic forces? Or something else entirely?
Is this term widely used outside the context of AFM?

I’m guessing intra-nuclear (within one nucleus) vs inter-atomic (bonding between two atoms). But that is a guess. Seems a bit sloppy for sure.

Consider the preceding words in the text: He compares the energy required to remove a nucleon from a nucleus, and then the energy required to free an electron from an atom. The force comparison is comparing the force binding a proton to a nucleus with an electron to an atom.

Yes, I agree this is the context. In my ~40 years of exposure to this topic, I have never come across this term in this fashion before.
